# Why is my code generating the error : Expecting a single value: [extent=3]?

Tags: c++, r, dataframe, rcpp

I am learning to be familiar with the Rcpp package and I have an R data frame **df** with list columns generated in two steps:

```
df<- data.frame(w= 1:3, x=3:5, y=6:8, z = I(list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)))

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df[1:3], function(x) Map("*", 
         df$z, x))))

>df
           w                x                  y
        1, 2             3, 6              6, 12
     2, 4, 6         4, 8, 12          7, 14, 21
 3, 6, 9, 12    5, 10, 15, 20      8, 16, 24, 32
```

I am working with a data set of almost 2 million rows. To save time long time for unnesting, I want to directly access the data frame and perform the following operation directly with Rcpp dispositions, to generate a data frame **df1**.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame (4*sin(df*pi))
```

Mostly inspired by information from this site, I have structured my code which I expected to be able to work, in the following way :

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector transfo(Rcpp::DataFrame x) {
    int nrow = x.nrow(), ncol = x.ncol();
    NumericVector out(nrow*ncol);
    int pi;
    int vol = 4;

    for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
            out[i, j] = sin(x[i,j]*pi)*vol;
            } 
        }
        return out;
    }')
```

But with `transfo(df)`:
 I get the error :

```
Expecting a single value: [extent=3].
```

I will be grateful for any hint on where my error comes.

Comment: You have a very non-standard type. You wrote a program expecting a standard data type. It failed.  Guess why -- you need either standardise your data, or cope with the non-standardness.  Still no free lunch ...

Comment: a hint on how to do that? Need some expert advice...

Comment: Rcpp has a `Rcpp::DataFrame` class. Have you tried using that as a function argument?

Comment: Using Rcpp::DataFrame as function argument as in NumericVector transfo(Rcpp::DataFrame x) gives the error: Error in transfo(df) : Expecting a single value: [extent=3].

Comment: Using `Rcpp:DataFrame` is more complicated than just replacing the argument type. That's why this was a comment and not an answer. Did you try the answer I provided?

Comment: Check `tibble::as.tibble(df)`. In fact, you have [list-columns](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1) here.

Comment: @F.Privé...Great!! unnesting did the job but created more rows. Any hint on the required structure to iterate through a data frame in Rcpp on Rstudio and perform the mathematical operations? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure is very unusual, and I am not sure that you will get a lot of spead-up from using C++ here. But you can use something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame df_sin(DataFrame df) {
  R_xlen_t nCols = df.cols();
  R_xlen_t nRows = df.rows();
  List result(nCols * nRows);
  result.attr("dim") = Dimension(nRows, nCols);
  colnames(result) = as<CharacterVector>(df.names());

  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < nCols; ++i) {
    List column = as<List>(df[i]);
    for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < nRows; ++j) {
      NumericVector tmp = as<NumericVector>(column[j]);
      result[i * nCols + j] = 4 * sin(tmp * M_PI);
    }
  }
  DataFrame df1(result);
  return df1;
}

/*** R
df <- data.frame(w= 1:3, x=3:5, y=6:8, z = I(list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)))
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df[1:3], 
                                          function(x) Map("*", df$z, x))))
df_sin(df)
*/
```

Note that I have switched from source code as string argument to `Rcpp::cppFunction()` to a separate `.cpp` file. Such a file can be conveniently edited in any editor that knows about C++, which includes RStudio. In RStudio, you can than source the file (Ctrl-Shift-Return or the source button), which will compile and link the code. In addition, the R code within the special R comment in the end will be executed. This is convenient if you need only a little R code together with your C++ code. If the C++ code is part of a larger R code base, then you can call `Rcpp::sourceCpp(<cppFile>)` within the R code. This will again compile and link the code as well as make the exported functions available in R. In that case, it is probably easier to remove the special R comment in the end, since that is executed with every call to `sourceCpp`.

Comment: 1 18 C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Documents\Untitled1.cpp [Error] Rcpp.h: No such file or directory...Not able to get along with this...Any documentation to help?

Comment: @Charles Did you use `Rcpp::sourceCpp("<cppFile>")`? See the introductory and attributes vignette for documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much but please is there a possibility for  me to have the operation performed only on Rstudio? It would be preferable for me